"or until" and "and until"

This warranty lasts until four years after purchase of the car or the odometer records 100 000 miles, whichever comes first.
The administrator of this organization shall serve for two years and until his successor takes office.

Might there be some convention according to which "or until" is used for whichever happens earlier and "and until" for whichever happens later, perhaps in legal writing or in some other specialty? It makes sense, but that doesn't necessarily means it's a conventional usage taught as a standard thing in some community of users.

The first sentence could equally well be "This warranty lasts until four years after purchase of the car or the odometer records 100 000 miles, whichever comes later." There's a reason legal documents normally add "whichever comes first/later/last".

No warrantee prepared by lawyers will read "This warranty lasts until four years after purchase of the car" It would be "lasts for a period of four years from the purchase."

The second sentence might make a clearer comparison if it added "whichever comes later."

@YosefBaskin :  Why is "from" instead of "after" important?

Four years after the purchase could stretch to five years, which is also four years after.

There's nothing special being contributed by "until" here; it's just that the first example is an actual "or" situation and the second example is an actual "and" situation. The administrator serves for two years, PLUS some extra time, as much as is needed until the handover. It could just as easily have been "two years and a day." "And" is used simply because something is being added.
Similarly, the first example creates an "either/or" option. The warranty might end in four years, or the warranty might end when the odometer hits 100,000.
"Until" has no bearing on these choices.

I'd prefer 'and then until'.
